# Add attributes to link in CKEditor 4 in Drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

I want to add rel="nofollow" to all links in the CKEditor. I have read a lot of questions about it and also tried my best with the documentation. However I cannot get it working.

I am using Drupal 7 (Not the wysiwyg module, just the ckeditor module with cdn version 4).

Code that I have tried:

```
var editor = new CKEDITOR.editor();
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( ev ) {
  editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
  {
    elements :
    {
      a : function( element )
      {
        console.log(element.attributes);
          if ( !element.attributes.rel )
              element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This code was what I found in other questions. In the documentation I can't find the addRules function, and if I put a breakpoint inside of the function, I see that it never gets called.

I would really appreciate some input!

Comment: Not exactly what you need but maybe you can use jQuery for adding rel attribute. Just add some class to container object where you are printing wysiwyg content and use jQuery to add rel to all links inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to get it done through CKeditor's config? Because This can be configurated within the Drupal interface:

1. **Configuration > Text formats > Choose the input format ex: Filtered HTML**
2. check **Limit allowed HTML tags**
3. scroll down to the vertical tab **Limit allowed HTML tags**
4. check **Add rel="nofollow" to all links**

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I didn't find this easy solution when I googled :)